# Bootstrap date time picker display format vs value format

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I am using the following plugin for selecting date and time.

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It works great in most cases. However in some cases I display the date in the input field as MM/DD/YYYY but when I submit to server, I need it as YYYY-MM-DD

What is the best way to accomplish this? I am thinking of overriding submit function for the form. But I kind of want to avoid this as I would like to somehow do it all using their events so I can contain the code in one place instead of adding a bunch of logic for each form.

Comment: have you tried the change event?

Comment: @Sushil I have not; but I am not sure this will work because the field can have a default value and might never change. I suppose I could have a load event as well as change. I am surprised more people haven't come across this.

Comment: yeah I guess more people are not using this or they might have not come across this situation. but I think the change function should be the place you should be targeting otherwise u'll have to write it in the form submit code as u mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Ashish and Chris code may work, but since [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker requires Moment.js](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#minimal-requirements), why not use [Moment.js Parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) (to parse the date from your custom or locale format chosen for the datepicker) and [Moment.js Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) (to convert the date in ISO format e.g. to be sent to an ASP.NET controller or other endpoints accepting that kind of format for DateTime)?

So the code would be way much shorter, like this:

```
  $('#datetimepicker1').on("dp.change",
    function (e) {
      var submitDateString = '';
      if (e.Date) {
        submitDateString = e.Date.format();
      }
      $("#datetime-submit").val(submitDateString);
    });
```

Note (see comment below): `e.Date` may need to be `e.date` to work.

Explanation:

- the dp.change event (e) has a Date property, which is a moment object, so you don't even need to care what was the date format you chose for the datepicker.
- when the datepicker is cleared e.Date is false, thus the if check.
- $("#datepicker1") is the input field where I bind bootstrap
  datepicker.
- $("#datetime-submit") is my hidden input field.

To answer the OP, if the desired format to submit is "YYYY-MM-DD", then use:

```
submitDateString = e.Date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

I just discovered [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and love it. Use it to make date parsing & displaying easier.

Comment: This worked for me, except it needed to be lowercase `e.date`, not `e.Date`

Answer (score 0):

I also face same problem. and i resolve this problem using hidden control.

in display Input filed Display date in MM/DD/YYYY

and take other one hidden value filed in  YYYY/MM/DD

and On change event of display date picker 
convert MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD format  using java script and put into hidden value format filed

Comment: Can you share your code for the conversion? I will have date formats of MM/DD/YYYY and DD-MM-YYYY

Comment: its simple javascript code. this code is not with me... if you want than i send whole code after 12 hours

Comment: I am sure I could figure it out; ideally I think there might be easy conversions using moment.js

Comment: ok good, if in case you need code than tell me . i will send you after 12 hours once i have code

Comment: IT would be great if you could post it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```
function date_time_picker_field_report($field, format)
{
    var id_of_field = $field.attr('id');
    var name_of_field = $field.attr('name');

    var id_copy_of_field = id_of_field+'_copy';
    var name_copy_of_field = name_of_field+'_copy';

    //Set $field to be a copy that is used for actual display of date info
    $field.attr('id', id_copy_of_field);
    $field.attr('name', name_copy_of_field);

    //create hidden input to track field behind the scenes (better value)
    $('<input>').attr({
        type: 'hidden',
        id: id_of_field,
        name: name_of_field
    }).insertAfter($field);


   $field.on("dp.change", function(e) 
    {   
        //If we have a space seperator it has a time; otherwise just a date (time has 2 spaces; between date + time and AM/PM (12 hour))
        var does_date_have_time = format.indexOf(' ') != -1;
        var date = e.date;

        var formated_date = null;

        if (does_date_have_time)
        {
            formated_date = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
        }
        else
        {
            formated_date = date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        }

        $('#'+id_of_field).val(formated_date);
   });

    var defaultDate = null;

    if (id_of_field == 'start_date')
    {
        defaultDate = moment();
        defaultDate.set('hour', 0);
        defaultDate.set('minute', 0);
    }
    else if(id_of_field == 'end_date')
    {
        defaultDate = moment();
        defaultDate.set('hour', 23);
        defaultDate.set('minute', 59);
    }

   $field.datetimepicker({format: format, locale: LOCALE, defaultDate: defaultDate});   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="fromDate"> 
<input id="fromDateDisplay" class="form-control datefilter" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" readonly="readonly">

$('#fromDateDisplay').datetimepicker({
    pickTime: false
});

$('#fromDateDisplay').on("dp.change",function (e) {
    $(this).blur().change();
    var d=new Date($("#fromDateDisplay").val());  
    $("#fromDate").val(dateParserForDatePicker(d)); 
});

//this function is use for converting date into MM/DD/YYYY format display
function dateParserForDatePicker(date) {    
    return ('0'+(date.getMonth()+1)).slice( -2 )+"/"+('0'+(date.getDate())).slice(-2)+"/"+date.getFullYear();
}
```